# UIimagejpegrepresentation compression quality vs other algorithms

Tags: ios, swift, image, jpeg, image-compression

We’ve been asked to consider how Instagram structures their image upload on iOS. Instagram compresses to a max 1080 x1350 and I've tried to achieve their image quality with those parameters using

```
UIimagejpegrepresentation
```

Does anyone know if they're likely to use apple's standard JPEG compression above or something custom/better?

Answer (score 0):

The way to find out is to take some Instragram JPEGs. Then run a JPEG dumping program on them.

Check the following to see if they are the same in all images:

1. Huffman tables in the DHT markers
2. The type of SOF marker used
3. The sampling rates in the SOF markers
4. The quantization tables in the DQT markers
   If they are using a progressive SOF marker:
5. The number of scans and their header values.

That will tell you if Instagram uses one thing. If it is, it is likely to be different from what you get from Apple.